# How to write to Program Files (x86) in C#?

Tags: c#

A requirement of the application I am developing is to be able to install a plugin for an external program. Installing a plugin consists of dropping a dll into a plugins directory. The trouble is that the plugins directory is located in a folder in Program Files (x86). When attempting to write to it via File.WriteAllBytes, I encounter an UnauthorizedAccessException.

- This error occurs even if the program is Run as administrator.
- I have tried modifying my manifest to level requireAdministrator.
- I have also tried spawning a new process with with runas.

How can I drop my dll into a folder inside Program Files (x86)?

Comment: Might be a UAC problem.

Comment: Even after accepting the UAC prompt, FileWriteBytes continues to throw an UnauthorizedAccessException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am silly. I specified the directory inside Program Files I was writing to, but did not include the filename in the path. The UnauthorizedAccessException threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
```

above your method that involves the IO activity. F/E, the following copies "myFile" to the program files directory:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
public void copyFile(string myFile){
    System.IO.File.Copy(myFile,Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your login account that is used to login to windows and start programming with that is not real administrator account.

Try to check your account permission and run visual studio as administrator mode and 
see if you can write in debug mode.

Check it and give the result.