# Where to put txt file in VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inno-setup

I have a c# script in VS 2019 and now I want to write values to a File but where do Ihave to put the .txt file? After that I want to make a Setup.exe with Inno Setup Compiler.

So my question is where do I put the file to get access to it during programming my Programm and after I installed my .exe after I installed it from the Setup.exe.

I heard something about this but I dont know what this does:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "combinations.txt");
```

Now i set the Permission on top of the function as it was mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382966/how-to-write-to-program-files-x86-in-c/39382987#39382987) but i still get the problem

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("g");
        string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        string logFile = "combinations.txt";

        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(exePath, logFile)) == false)
            File.Create(Path.Combine(exePath, logFile));

        using (StreamWriter wr = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(exePath, logFile)))
        {
            wr.WriteLine(date + "|" + date);
            wr.Close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try to look at the documentation to understand that line of code?  Here for you [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath), [Environement.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder), [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this path correctly
it's in the folder where your exe works.

for example a writing log file in the exe folder.
in debug mode its in the debug folder.

```
public static void LogWrite(string mes)
        {
            string exepath= Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location); 
            DateTime _dt = DateTime.Now;
            string logFile= "Log.Inc";
                  
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(exepath, logFile)) == false)
                File.Create(Path.Combine(exepath, logFile));

            using (StreamWriter wr = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(exepath, logFile)))
            {
                wr.WriteLine(_dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "|" + _dt.ToString("hh:mm") + "|" + mes);
                wr.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Usually writing a file in the same folder where the exe exists works perfectly when debugging and fails when deploying. The folder needs to have the correct permissions and this is not the case with some predefined folders like "Program Files"

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, but do i have to add this file at the Inno Setup Complier? or is it automatically added in the .exe?

Comment: i like your case; i didnt try it before  but  find a topic about it also did not try the solution . take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382987/8970570

Comment: @mcbabo in your case, if it is not exist  in your exe path after installation, it will create itself.   but Steve's case; the method i give can take error about permission.

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The Access to the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Lotto\combinations.txt" was denied. Still get the error

Comment: before create the File  add   File.SetAttributes(Path.Combine(exepath, logFile), FileAttributes.Normal); maybe it can work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, you can try try the following code to log the information to the txt file when you have published it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("g");
            string exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            string logFile = "combinations.txt";

            using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(exePath, logFile), true))
            {
                wr.WriteLine(date + "|" + date);
                wr.Close();
            }
            string path = Path.Combine(exePath, logFile);
            MessageBox.Show(path);
        }
```

If you use the above code, there is no need to check if the file is created.
Also, I show the path of the txt file in the final code.

Comment: in the Vs debug it works fine but after i compile it with Inno i get this error:System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ My Program \ combinations.txt" was denied.

Comment: @mcbabo, have you tried my code? Because I didn't meet the exception you mentioned. And my path is 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\TK36Y70O.P6H\DEQ0P9YH.GOD\test..tion_37468889c7e228bf_0001.0000_367029bb9a351021\combinations.txt'. You can check it again. By the way, I used visual studio to publish the program.

Comment: when i ran the .exe it it worked fine but when i do an installer and ran the .exe from the installer i get the error